# Kill subprocess if it becomes interactive

Tags: rust, pdflatex

I have the following code that runs `pdflatex`:

```
    let _p2 = Command::new("pdflatex")
        .arg("document.tex")
        .arg("-interaction=batchmode")
        .current_dir(&compile_dir)
        .spawn()
        .expect("There was an error")
        .wait();
```

The problem is sometimes there are errors in the input document.tex (for example a missing closing `$` for a math formula). What happens then is the terminal starts asking for user input. That is not what I want, I want the process to be killed instead (and an error sent to the user).

I've looked around the `pdflatex --help` but could not find any options that cancels compilation if it encounters any errors.

What would be the way to tell `Command` that if it encounters any interactivity, then it needs to kill the process?

Is there some way to send in a Ctrl+C cancel command via `.stdin()`?

Comment: You need to reorder the arguments; `-interaction=batchmode` needs to go before the file name to apply to that file.

Comment: Thank you @SvenMarnach, that did the trick! I've also added `-halt-on-error` for pdflatex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exact behavior entirely depends on the subprocess (`pdflatex` in this case).

[By default](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Command.html#method.stdin), a subprocess launched via `.spawn()` will [inherit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#method.inherit) the `stdin` file descriptor from the parent. Since the parent process has it's `stdin` attached to an interactive terminal, the `pdflatex` will inherit that and read from the same terminal.
What you can try to do is to [close](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/process/struct.Stdio.html#method.null) `pdflatex`'s `stdin` before launching it, via `.stdin(Stdio::null())`. This will a) detach `stdin` for the `pdflatex`-process from the parent process and hence from the terminal and b) hopefully signal to the `pdflatex`-process that no user input is to be expected (or even possible; reading from `stdin` will immediately result in `EOF`).
It is up to `pdflatex` what happens, though. It is possible that `pdflatex` just blocks and waits forever for user input on a closed `stdin`; that would be considered a bug, yet it is what it is.

Comment: This happens to work fine for pdflatex, but I'd still prefer `pdflatex -interaction=batchmode document.tex` – it's the documented way of running pdflatex in a non-interactive way.

Comment: I've tried the above method, yes it works in a general sense. However, as per comment from @SvenMarnach, I was using the `pdflatex` incorrectly, so have re-ordered the arguments and got the desired outcome.